# How to solve this equation: $v_1\partial_xu+v_2\partial_y u=0$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I have the following equation:
$$
v_1\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x}+v_2\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial y}=0 \tag{1}$$
$u(x,y)$ is the unknown function (a scalar-valued function), $v_1$ and $v_2$ are two scalars.

---

I tried to solve it like this:

We can write the previous equation as follows:
$$\mathbf v\cdot \nabla u=0\tag{2}$$ where $\mathbf v= (v_1, v_2)^T$.

From the equation $(2)$ we can notice that the directional derivative of $u$ in the $\mathbf v$ direction is $0$.

That means $u$ is constant along lines parallel to $\mathbf v$.
Which can be translted to:
 $$(x,y)^T \cdot (v_2, -v_1)^T = k \Rightarrow v_2x-v_1y = k$$ $k$ is an arbitrary constant. Hence $$u=f(v_2x-v_1y)$$ $f $ is an arbitrary function.
Can you please, explain this last step mathematicaly? why does the relation 
$v_2x-v_1y=k$ imply $u = f(v_2x-v_1y)$?

Comment: What are your boundary conditions?

Comment: @AlexR.: in general case, we will get a solution in the form : $u = f(v_2x-v_1y)$ where $f$ is an arbitrary function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume that $v_1^2+v_2^2\neq 0$.  Write $u(x,y)=U(z,w)$ with $$z:=v_1x+v_2y\text{ and }w:=v_2x-v_1y\,.$$  Hence, $$x=\frac{v_1z+v_2w}{v_1^2+v_2^2}\text{ and }y=\frac{v_2z-v_1w}{v_1^2+v_2^2}\,.$$
Observe that $z$ and $w$ are independent (by checking that $\frac{\partial z}{\partial w}=0$ and $\frac{\partial w}{\partial z}=0$). Then, you can see that $$\frac{\partial U}{\partial z}=\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\,\frac{\partial x}{\partial z}+\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\,\frac{\partial y}{\partial z}=\frac{1}{v_1^2+v_2^2}\left(v_1\,\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+v_2\,\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\right)=0\,.$$
That is, $U(z,w)$ depends only on $w$.  Hence, $U(z,w)=f(w)$ for some function $f$.  That is, $$u(x,y)=U(z,w)=f(w)=f\left(v_2x-v_1y\right)\,.$$

Comment: in the chain rule, do you mean $\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial z}$  or $\dfrac{\partial U}{\partial z}$?

Comment: Just as I wrote.  I avoid using $u$ as a function of $z$, so $\frac{\partial u}{\partial z}$ is not a good notation in my opinion.